# how to make custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, app-shortcuts

i'm new to elementryOS, using elementryOS Juno.

i want to make as much as possible custom keyboard shortcuts for myself.
so i would need to use my mouse as little as possible.

i mean like making ctrl + alt + s to open my system settings and such.
in my windows i've used the run prompt with shortcuts in the PATH, so i could have run shortcuts with shortcuts in the prompt.
i was hoping that in linux there will even be an option to make my own keyboard shortcuts.

is there any option like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to eOS, and Linux, too.

Just try to use Custom Shortcuts to launch apps. It seems do the trick.
[image: Custom Keyboard Shortcuts to Launch Application]

For the Command Line to launch specific app, *AppEditor* have some handy informaitons. As I'm not familar with command line.
[image: AppEditor]

*AppEditor* can be installed from AppCenter:

https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor

No idea is it a proper way. Any experienced user, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Open System settings > keyboard and there you will find "Shortcuts" tab, contains all the shortcuts. You can freely assign any key or combination you want. you can add custom command and bind it to any key/combination as well